# Why does getExternalFilesDir save my file to Internal Storage

Tags: android

I just started developing an android app so I need your help guys.

Here's my code.

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
        File image = null;
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date()); //Get Date
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); //Get the directory of pictures


        if (isExertnalStorageWritable()){
            if(isExternalStorageReadable()) {
                image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir); //Create the temp file
                mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
            }
        }

        return image;
    }
```

but my temp file is always being created in the internal storage, not in the External storage.

Comment: try Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to get the base folder of the device, and not the app specific folder

Comment: Hey there is a lot of confusion when it comes to deal with Internal/External Storage. Have a look on this article https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

// Use this code changes to make your data to be stored in your external storage

```
File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir("Pictures");
```

Answer (score 0):

`File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);`

I believe in this line you are asking for the directory of pictures that are listed for the user. Try pasing null instead like this:

```
File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
```

Let me know if that worked for you! Good luck!